# Como fazer três sombras curvas com CSS num elemento retangular

Tags: css

Gostaria de fazer sombras curvas nas arestas da esquerda, direita e inferior de um elemento retangular. Sabendo que só tenho um `:after` e um `:before`, ligeiramente eu usaria eles para sombrear as arestas da horizontal, mas e a inferior?

Segue uma imagem do que eu preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algum manjador pode me dar uma força? :L

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse artigo: [Criando Box Shadows](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects)